# Port forwarding like FPipe.exe on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, nat

Hello I want to forward port A of my host to port B of another host, in Linux I always use:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport A -j DNAT --to-destination dest:B
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d dest -p tcp -m tcp --dport B -j SNAT --to-source myhost
```

And FPipe on Windows did the trick too:

```
FPipe.exe -l A -r B dest -v -c 2048
```

But the FPipe application will reset the connection if connection speed > 32KB/s, and I have no way to bypass this.

So could anyone help me with this - tell me how to use fpipe correctly or recommend another freeware to do this thing?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [PJS Passport](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/) - don't know whether it is configurable from the command line, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Port_Forwarding_or_Port_Mapping).

Comment: Will this also work on Windows? The Wikipedia article states "On Linux, NetCat can be used for port forwarding", which seems to indicate it doesn't.

Comment: @Frank: I believe there are Windows ports: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Variants)

Comment: I tried the windows version of netcat but it does not support "-c" yet, which is needed to do port forwarding.

Comment: @Felix - I think the `-e` option does what you want.  At least that's what I understand from the docs.  But glad the other tool helped.

Comment: I tried but failed... The connection will be terminated right after it actually connected, and giving an error "